# How to Access Sorted Pipe Array (generated with *ngFor and pipes) from Controller in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

How can I access a variable declared in an *ngFor inside the controller?

I have code that looks like this:

```
<song *ngFor="let track of music | async | sortMusic: [sortBy] as sortedTracks" [trackInfo]="track" (click)="toggleTrack(track)"></song>
```

I want to access the "sortedTracks" variable. I'm interested in accessing it from the component that has the code above and not from the song component controller.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Why don't you want to just sort an array before you hand it to 'ngFor'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

Indeed it should be easy:

```typescript
@ViewChild(NgForOf) ngForDir: NgForOf<any>;

this.ngForDir.ngForOf
```

**[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ennqpc?file=app/app.component.ts)**

**Old version**

1) Special directive

We can write directive that helps me to get it:

**ngfor-as.directive.ts**

```typescript
import { Directive, EmbeddedViewRef, NgIterable, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForOfContext } from '@angular/common';

@Directive({
    selector: '[ngForOf]'
})
export class NgForOfAsDirective<T> {
    constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef) {}

    public get asValue(): NgIterable<T> {
      const viewRef = this.vcRef.get(0) as EmbeddedViewRef<NgForOfContext<T>>;
      return viewRef ? viewRef.context.ngForOf : null;
    }
}
```

As soon as we have created directive above we can use `@ViewChild` to get instance of this directive:

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <song *ngFor="let track of music | async | sortMusic: sortBy as sortedTracks" ...></song>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  ...

  @ViewChild(NgForOfAsDirective) ngForAs: NgForOfAsDirective<any[]>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.ngForAs.asValue);
  }
}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f6ssbz?file=app%2Fngfor-as.directive.ts)**

2) Getting value directly from ViewContainerRef

In case you don't want to create a directive you can just get hold of `ViewContainer` that is used by `ngForOf` directive:

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <song *ngFor="let track of music | async | sortMusic: sortBy as sortedTracks" ...></song>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild(TemplateRef, { read: ViewContainerRef }) vcRef: ViewContainerRef;

  get asMusicValue(): NgIterable<any> {
    const viewRef = this.vcRef.get(0) as EmbeddedViewRef<NgForOfContext<any>>;
    return viewRef ? viewRef.context.ngForOf : null;
  }

  ...

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.asMusicValue);
  }
}
```

**[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-foeufz?file=app/app.component.ts)**

---

Of course, if you have several `ngForOf` directives in your template then you should be more precise when querying `ViewContainerRef`.

For that you could use one of these options:

- `@ViewChildren` if know the exact order ([example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4fgnzh?file=app/app.component.ts))

---

```typescript
@ViewChildren(TemplateRef, { read: ViewContainerRef }) vcRefs: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;
...
this.vcRefs.first.get(0)
            ^^^^^
```

- Expanded form of `ngForOf` ([example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rfs1jx?file=app/app.module.ts)):

---

```typescript
<ng-template #someId 
   let-track 
   ngFor 
   [ngForOf]="music | async | sortMusic: sortBy" 
   let-sortedTracks="ngFor">
  <song [trackInfo]="track"></song>
</ng-template>
```

- Directive with special selector ([example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hhycph?file=app/app.component.ts))

---

```typescript
@Directive({
  selector: '[ngForOf=music | async | sortMusic: sortBy ]'
})
export class NgForOfMusic {}

...
@ViewChild(NgForOfMusic, { read: ViewContainerRef }) vcRef: ViewContainerRef;
```

It will match

```typescript
*ngFor="let track of music | async | sortMusic: sortBy as sortedTracks" 
                     |                                    | 
                      \                                  /
                                   attrValue
```

but don't use square brackets like:

```typescript
*ngFor="let track of music | async | sortMusic: [sortBy] as sortedTracks"
```

because selector

```typescript
@Directive({
  selector: '[ngForOf=music | async | sortMusic: [sortBy] ]'
})
```

won't work.